# Error: docker-engine-selinux conflicts with 2:container-selinux?

Tags: linux, docker, centos

1. Centos 7. During installing Docker it says error:

~ wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sh

```
+ sh -c 'sleep 3; yum -y -q install docker-engine'

Error: docker-engine-selinux conflicts with 2:container-selinux-1.10.3-59.el7.centos.x86_64

 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem

** Found 13 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:

audit-libs-2.6.5-3.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with audit-libs-2.4.1-5.el7.x86_64
7:device-mapper-1.02.135-1.el7_3.1.x86_64 is a duplicate with 7:device-mapper-1.02.93-3.el7_1.1.x86_64

7:device-mapper-libs-1.02.135-1.el7_3.1.x86_64 is a duplicate with 7:device-mapper-libs-1.02.93-3.el7_1.1.x86_64

kmod-20-9.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with kmod-14-10.el7.x86_64

libselinux-2.5-6.el7.x86_64 has installed conflicts systemd < ('0', '219', '20'): systemd-208-20.el7_1.5.x86_64

libselinux-2.5-6.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with libselinux-2.2.2-6.el7.x86_64

libselinux-utils-2.5-6.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with libselinux-utils-2.2.2-6.el7.x86_64

libsemanage-2.5-4.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with libsemanage-2.1.10-16.el7.x86_64

libsepol-2.5-6.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with libsepol-2.1.9-3.el7.x86_64

policycoreutils-2.5-9.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with policycoreutils-2.2.5-15.el7.x86_64

systemd-219-30.el7_3.6.x86_64 has installed conflicts initscripts < ('0', '9.49.28', '1'): initscripts-9.49.24-1.el7.x86_64

systemd-219-30.el7_3.6.x86_64 is a duplicate with systemd-208-20.el7_1.5.x86_64

systemd-libs-219-30.el7_3.6.x86_64 is a duplicate with systemd-libs-208-20.el7_1.5.x86_64
```

How to fix these?

2. When i use 'yum update', i take the errors:

   libselinux conflicts with systemd

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem, and managed to solve it.
What I did:

Look for a previous CentOs native docker install remnant and remove it:

```
[root@here ~]# rpm -aq | grep docker
docker-common-1.10.3-59.el7.centos.x86_64
[root@here ~]# yum remove docker*
```

That was not enough though

Look for that `container-selinux` and remove it too:

```
[root@here ~]# rpm -qa | grep container-selinux
container-selinux-1.10.3-59.el7.centos.x86_64
```

First make sure it is not used by anything else (I had a doubt, I chose to play safe)

```
[root@here ~]# rpm -q --whatrequires container-selinux-1.10.3-59.el7.centos.x86_64
no package requires container-selinux-1.10.3-59.el7.centos.x86_64
[root@here ~]# yum remove container-selinux
```

and then I was good !

Comment: this helps me a lot